# SKView bounds.size get inverted on touch event (Sprite Kit)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene, skview

Please help me understand the following behavior (iOS Sprite Kit).

The output of the code I present below is:

1.skView.bounds.size = 768.00, 1024.00

2.skView.bounds.size = 1024.00, 768.00

As seen above, width and height are switched between the two methods, and that causes my second scene to be presented not in the correct scale.

My game will run in landscape mode only, which means that in fact, the second width x height ratio is the correct one (though it is the first that renders the scene in the correct aspect ratio, which in itself is a mystery to me).

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this behavior? What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.currentGameState = GS_INTRO_SCENE;

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.

    printf("1.skView.bounds.size = %.2f, %.2f\n", skView.bounds.size.width, skView.bounds.size.height);

    SKScene *scene = [SKTGameIntroScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (self.currentGameState == GS_INTRO_SCENE) {
        self.currentGameState = GS_GAME_PLAY;

        SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

        printf("2.skView.bounds.size = %.2f, %.2f\n", skView.bounds.size.width, skView.bounds.size.height);

        SKScene *nextScene = [SKTMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        nextScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        SKTransition *fadeIn = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:5.0f];

        [skView presentScene:nextScene transition:fadeIn];
    }
}
```

I greatly appreciate it in advance.

**** edit: ****

@giorashc solved my problem suggesting I move the scene initiation to -(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews method.

But my second scene remains stretched.... here is the full code for SKTViewController.m after the change (can anyone say why second view is still stretched?):

```
//
//  SKTViewController.m
//  SpriteKitTest
//
//  Created by Claudia Dazcal on 13/07/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 DazcalFamily_inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SKTViewController.h"
#import "SKTMyScene.h"
#include "SKTGameIntroScene.h"

typedef enum
{
    GS_INTRO_SCENE,
    GS_GAME_PLAY
}GameStates;

@interface SKTViewController ()

@property GameStates currentGameState;
@property BOOL firstSceneLoaded;

@end

@implementation SKTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.currentGameState = GS_INTRO_SCENE;

    self.firstSceneLoaded = NO;

}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    if (!self.firstSceneLoaded) {
        self.firstSceneLoaded = YES;

        // Configure the view.
        SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
        skView.showsFPS = YES;
        skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

        // Create and configure the scene.

        printf("1.skView.bounds.size = %.2f, %.2f\n", skView.bounds.size.width, skView.bounds.size.height);

        SKScene *scene = [SKTGameIntroScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];

    }

}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (self.currentGameState == GS_INTRO_SCENE) {
        self.currentGameState = GS_GAME_PLAY;

        SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

        printf("2.skView.bounds.size = %.2f, %.2f\n", skView.bounds.size.width, skView.bounds.size.height);

        //CGSize DebugSize = CGSizeMake(skView.bounds.size.height, skView.bounds.size.width);

        //SKScene *nextScene = [SKTMyScene sceneWithSize:DebugSize];
        SKScene *nextScene = [SKTMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        nextScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        //SKTransition *fadeIn = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:5.0f];

        //[skView presentScene:nextScene transition:fadeIn];
        [skView presentScene:nextScene];
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

@end
```

*** edit 2 ****

Ok, it`s all sorted out now.

@giorashc solved my problem right away when he suggested moving the scene initiation to viewWillLayoutSubviews. It turns out that since I was previously working with the wrong bounds, I set up my original scene with the wrong values and now that it was fixed, it looked stretched.

But it`s fixed now. Thank you so much @giorashc!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your scene in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method. In this method the view bounds are updated correctly.

Make sure though that you initialize the scene only once as this method is called whenever the view controller presents another view controller or the application is changing its orientation.

Comment: Thank you, it did solve the switched aspect ratio I saw. But my second scene is still stretched with the aspect ratio switched (even though I do see in my output the aspect ratio is not in fact switched)... any idea as to why??

Comment: where do you create your second scene? can you show the code? (Edit your question with the code if possible)

Comment: before presenting the second scene what bounds are printed ? are they as you expect them to be ?

Comment: Thank you @giorashc. It is solved (thanks to you)... I explain it in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

In the first method the view hasn't rotated to landscape mode yet. In the second it has rotated to landscape mode so is now reporting bounds that are wider than it is tall.